# Django, accessing the top parent objects from second level parents from child with many to many realtaionship

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-queryset, one-to-many

I have a setup where I have these models.

Devices
Slideshows
Slides

The device can have only one slideshow
Slideshow can be assigned to many devices
The slide can be assigned to many slideshows

Now, I am trying to work my way up the tree to get all of the devices that have all the slideshows that the slide belongs to.

Lets say I have a hold of the 'slide 1' object. Is there a query that could get me all the devices at the top of the tree?

[image]

Currently, this is how I am traversing to the top as I need to send a post_save signal, it is working as is but I feel like it is a bad way to do it. and it's hard for even me to follow. I am using related names to go up the tree.

`related_name=devices`
`related_name=slideshows`

I was hoping to do something simple like `instance.slideshows.devices.all()` but that yields related manager errors or even `instance.slideshows.all().devices.all()`

```
    slideshows = instance.slideshows.all()

    related_devices = []
    for slideshow in slideshows:
        devices = slideshow.devices.all()
        related_devices = list(chain(related_devices, devices))

    for device in related_devices:
        post_save.send(Device, instance=device)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess it was easier than I thought!

`devices = Device.objects.filter(slideshow__slides=instance)`